# "foreach" but group the values for unique variables

Tags: php, foreach, grouping

I have arrays like this:

```
$array1=array("x=1","y=2","y=3","z=3");
$array2=array("x=1","y=4","y=3","t=1");
```

I wanna print it exactly like this:

```
x   y   z   t
1   2,3 3   
1   4,3     1
```

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Comment: Change the array to `array("x" => 1, "y" => 2, "y" => 3, "z" => 4);` if possible. Will make it easier to use.

Comment: @ FastTrack i'm trying after exploding '=' and using array_unique for variables is okay, but cannot group the values to the unique var. @BeatAlex it's the format of the text data, i've to use like this.

Comment: @Galatasaray Take a look at my answer below. I think i have what you want.

Comment: ty very much @Latheesan Kanes, if i have 2 different dimensions array, how can i get the output like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do it like this:

```
<?php

// Data Source
$array = array("x=1","y=2","y=3","z=3");

// Helper Function
function parseArray($array)
{
    // Init
    $parsed_array = array();

    // Process Array
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $item);
        $parsed_array[$key][] = $value;
    }

    // Finished
    return $parsed_array;
}

// Usage
var_dump(parseArray($array));
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you want it to display it in like the said format; this is what you do this:

```
// Usage
$parsed_data = parseArray($array);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>". implode('</th><th>', array_keys($parsed_data)) ."</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($parsed_data as $key => $values) {
    echo '<td>'.implode(',', $values).'</td>';
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = ["x=1","y=2","y=3","z=3"];
$multi = [];
foreach($arr as $value){
    $data = explode('=', $value);
    $multi[$data[0]][] = $data[1];
}

echo '<table><tr><th>';
echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys($multi));
echo '</th></tr><tr>';
foreach($multi AS $value){
    echo '<td>'.implode(',', $value).'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Output when rendered as html:

```
x   y   z
1   2,3 3
```

Comment: this works too, ty very much Jessica, if i have 2 different dimensions array, how can i get the output like my edited question?

Comment: Try it and then update with your code. You should be able to read and understand the code I gave you, if not what is confusing?